# MFC: CListCtrl background color of first row?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

When I create an MFC project, I add a dialog (IDD_DIALOG1) with CListCtrl of Report style. But when I test it, I see that its first row does not have grayish background.

[image]

However, this project "https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/608/Using-the-List-Control" has (note the row with "Item Name" etc). When I read its code, I cannot tell which part makes the difference.

[image]

My code is pretty much skeleton but can be accessed here "https://138.197.210.223/test/My.zip" if interested.

Comment: The "First Row" Is called Column Header. And typically you define them in `OnInitDialog()` (`WM_INITDIALOG`), using the `LVM_SETCOLUMN` message (or `ListView_SetColumn()` macro).

Comment: The column header is white in the Windows 8-10 (maybe even 7, don't remember) look. The ListCtrlDemo has the old Windows 2000 look where the column header was grey. Google "windows visual styles" for more details.

Comment: Aren't you using a `CMFCListCtrl` instead? Which by the way, is much better than a `CListCtrl`!